# Ajax Control Toolkit - Use client-side button to activate tab

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, client-side, tabs, tabcontainer, tabpanel

I'm using the TabContainer/TabPanel components of the Ajax Control Toolkit.

I'd like to hide the tabs themselves and use a button elsewhere on the page to activate (bring to the front) one of the tabs without posting back to the server.

I can show and hide the tabs by grabbing their clientIDs and manually setting the visibility and display styles.

But is there a javascript function I can call to do this and perform whatever magic happens behind the scenes when I click an actual tab?

Comment: I have worked with ACT before, although now I'm focused on CastleProject. You have access to all the "magic" behind TabContainer, I even proposed a patch to it sometime in the past.
You may want to check the JS code generated by ACT, it is scary but easy to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
var tab = $find(“tabContainer’s ClientID”);
tab.set_activeTabIndex(1); // active the second tab panel
tab.getFirstTab().set_enabled(false); // disable the first panel
```